# Reports With Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm trying to create a pretty advanced query within django and im having problems doing so, i can use the basic:

```
for obj in Invoice.objects.filter():
```

but if i try and move this into raw PostgreSQL query i get an error telling me that the relation does not exist am i doing something wrong, i am following the [Preforming raw SQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/sql/) on the django documents but i keep getting same error

full code:

```
def csv_report(request):
response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.csv"'

writer = csv.writer(response, csv.excel)
response.write(u'\ufeff'.encode('utf8'))
writer.writerow([
    smart_str(u"ID"),
    smart_str(u"value"),
    smart_str(u"workitem content type"),
    smart_str(u"created date"),
    smart_str(u"workitem.id"),
    smart_str(u"workitem"),
    smart_str(u"workitem_content_type"),
])
for obj in Invoice.objects.raw('SELECT * from twm_Invoice'):
    writer.writerow([
        smart_str(obj.pk),
        smart_str(obj.value),
        smart_str(obj.workitem_content_type),
        smart_str(obj.created_date),
        smart_str(obj.workitem_id),
        smart_str(obj.workitem),
        smart_str(obj.workitem_content_type),
    ])
return response
```

i have tried to use the app now within front of the model name and without none of them seem to work.

Thanks J

Comment: *Why* can't you use the normal filter? Is that the actual table name?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Im trying to get data from about 5 tables withing the database. I did not thing the filter function would be capable of this. Yeah its the real name :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try running your raw sql directly in the database.. my guess is that your table name is not correct, usually they're lowercase

BTW.. I hope you have a very good reason for using raw sql queries and not the awesome ORM ;)

Comment: Is the ORM capable of huge/multi table queries? hmm maybe i will have a read about it then. thanks.

Comment: the ORM will probably generate the same query you wrote, but with the ORM is easier to read, maintain, debug, test, reuse your code.. But sometimes you have a very complex query that is better to use a raw sql. It's up to you :)